# stats.chisquare wrongly returns p_value = 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, statistics

I have such expected and frequencies in each category as shown below:

[image]

[image]

They seem to be pretty similar, but chi square test doesn't think so:

```
stats.chisquare(city_ans.answered, city_ans.sent)
# Power_divergenceResult(statistic=893005.32003277098, pvalue=0.0)
```

Filtering values less than 10 doesn't change much:

```
stats.chisquare(city_ans[city_ans.answered > 10].answered, city_ans[city_ans.answered > 10].sent)

# Power_divergenceResult(statistic=892917.3023088905, pvalue=0.0)
```

What am I doing wrong? 
How can I apply F - test here?

PS. Using this test with the same values as obs and exp - return p_val = 1

```
stats.chisquare(city_ans.sent, city_ans.sent)
# Power_divergenceResult(statistic=0.0, pvalue=1.0)
```

However such code also should return p_val = 1, but it doesn't:

```
stats.chisquare(0.9*city_ans.sent, city_ans.sent)
# Power_divergenceResult(statistic=10591.249999999995, pvalue=0.0)
```

**UPD:**

```
f_obs = weeks_ans.answered / np.sum(weeks_ans.answered)
f_exp = weeks_ans.sent / np.sum(weeks_ans.sent)
stats.chisquare(f_obs, f_exp)

# Power_divergenceResult(statistic=0.064491479990141154, pvalue=1.0)
```

Its seems to pretty nice result but I think something isnt right here.

For example look to that distribution below, same approach:

```
# Power_divergenceResult(statistic=0.064491479990141154, pvalue=1.0)
```

Is it fair to use such test that the distribution are the same

[image]

Comment: How big is your data set?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser just 54 categories (x - axis), and frequencies - from very low values to up thousands

Comment: Do the big spikes occur at the same x values?  If not, they result in a huge discrepancy in the frequencies.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser no, they match

Comment: *"However such code also should return p_val = 1, but it doesn't: ..."* That's not correct.  The p-value is not a correlation coefficient.  Any difference in the values results in a positive chi-squared statistic, and that results in a p-value less than 1 (although if the difference is tiny, the numerically computed p-value might still be 1).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser You kind of right, but it doesnt return  something about 1, just 0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by @Crasy Ivan, the chisquare test needs the same number of observations or counts in observed and expected counts.

In this case, it seems to be that the data comes from two different samples. This is essentially a 2 by K contingency table and the hypothesis that each row has the same distribution will be corrected by the row totals in computing the expected frequency counts.

So using chisquare test directly is the wrong test for the two sample case. scipy.stats has the chisquare test for independence in contingency tables.

A general remark about very large counts which seems to be the case here:

As the sample size grows the null hypothesis will be rejected and the pvalue goes to zero for any small but nonzero deviation from the null hypothesis. With counts, i.e. total number of observations, of more that 50,000 the proper hypthesis test will most likely reject even small differences that are statistically significant but irrelevant in applications.

An alternative would be to use equivalence tests to test the hypothesis that the two distributions do not differ by more than some small margin. The difficulty is that it is difficult to specify what the equivalence thresholds should be in terms of some goodness-of-fit statistics.

Comment: You right. I applied contingency table from stats  - it rejects both cases, but it more sure for the second one. First case p_value = 10^-182, secind just zero

Comment: Can we apply binomial test here?

Comment: @Rocketq No, binomial is not appropriate because the data is multinomial, i.e. more than two frequencies or proportions. Binomial is for counts of a binary choice.

Comment: @Rocketq  Are your categories ordered or are the x labels 1, ... 50 just arbitrary labels? Based on the plot there are small differences, e.g. at 1 and 33 which are large in absolute term given that counts are in the thousands. It would be possible to bin neighboring values if they can be considered as small shifts in the count.

Comment: 1, ... 50 - are labeled stores. These are already counted number of observation of each label

Comment: stats.binom_test(1500, store.answered.sum(), 0.0233, alternative = 'two-sided')

I applied binom this way: 1500 observed amount, store.answered.sum() - sum over all observations, 0.0233 - expected frequency of that label

Comment: Damn, so that can we use as other test?

Comment: I think it would be best to ask on stats.stackexchange about which test or model to use, and describe the underlying sampling problem. I think multinomial model is not the right model if you don't want the extreme pvalue=0 answer. One of the underlying assumption is that all observations are drawn independently from the same distribution. This will not hold if there is correlation within a store or heterogeneity in the probabilities/distribution. In those cases the variance assumption of the multinomial/binomial/Poisson model would not hold and we get either under or over dispersion.